# Graphs in ASP.NET Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net, graph, medium-trust

I've tried to use MSChart and ZedGraph but they both require Full Trust. Are there any other graphing libraries that I could use in Medium Trust webhosting? I have to note that I have very low ASP.NET knowledge so far.

Thanks,
Petr

**EDIT:** At the end, ZedGraph seems to be running well in Medium Trust. I just added the following line to AssemblyInfo.cs in the ZedGraph source code, recompiled and all is running OK:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the google visualisation API - I use this in my project with great success.  This requires no component on the server, but does require the use of JavaScript.  They also have an API to create chart images which don't require JavaScript, though you are limited in the amount of data you can encode into a URL to produce these.

[Visualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/) ([Samples](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html))

[Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) ([Samples](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html))

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on this. Anyway, I will probably need to draw many points (say 20 curves with 50 points each), so I don't know if this will be usable.

Comment: It's definitely possible with the JavaScript one.  It's less likely using the charting library.  It just enables you to create graphs without any server-side component.